# Does the Method of Compliments also work for non-integers?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

I have only encountered the use of [Method of Complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements) for integers, not for non-integers, particularly in the field of modern programming.

However, my curiosity has gotten the best of me, and I am wondering if anyone has ever seen the Method of Complements applied to non-integers. Is it even feasible or practical?

Comment: Do you mean something like [real computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_computation) (a.k.a., computation over the reals)?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Im less interested in computation of the reals ( Im more focused on the different uses of this particular mathematical method)

Comment: Non integers tend to blush when complimented.